# Transfering iOS and Android App to different Developer Accounts - does Store Link for end users change?

Tags: android, ios, app-store, transfer, google-play-console

I'm about to transfer an App (both iOS and Android) from one developer account to another. There are lots of tutorials out there for the process, but there is one step I can't find any information about: Will the store link for the end-user change? Since the link doesn't include the name of the developer account for neither Android or iOS I assume it will stay the same, but I would like to be sure before starting the transfer.

The closest I found was this:
From: https://support.pressmatrix.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000863165-Transferring-Apps-to-a-different-Developer-Account

> What changes for the end user?
>
> The app is available to users during the transfer process without
>   interruption. Users will only see an update on the mobile device. Once
>   the app has been updated, the name of the publisher will be changed in
>   the app overview within the respective app stores.

Thanks for your help,
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the URLs will **not change**.

iOS: the URL is based on the Apple ID (numeric value) of the app. This value does not change with the transfer. (e.g. https://apps.apple.com/us/app/id529479190 Apple ID is **529479190**)

Android: the URL is based on the package name of the app. This value does not change with the transfer. (e.g. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.supercell.clashofclans&hl=en Package name is **com.supercell.clashofclans**)

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for your prompt and detailed answer, that helps a lot.